# how to change color of an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I am taking a beginners javascript class.  My teacher wants me to change the color of an element in my page, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is the page:

```
// JavaScript Document

function myPar() {

    pge = new Array ()

    //I would need to change the color of JUST pge[4]

    pge[4] = "So have you reverse engineered this document?"

    pge[3] = "This first instance a button creation will create multiple buttons with no purpose. They will not be linked to any site in this lecture video. The first need to become familiar with the process and with the required syntax for setting a series of attributes. When the button construction sequence is completed the process will then append the button to the body tag as it did for the paragraph tag."

    pge[2] = "The same process that was used to create paragraphs dynamically will be used to create buttons dynamically. This first instance of button creation will be design to create a button each time the function trigger is pressed."

    pge[5] = "So this build of page content can happen in any sequence that is seen fit and then modified by changing index vaues."

    pge[0] = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times"

    pge[1]= "There's no way that we can work out a way to colonize Mars in the next 50 years.  Think of the logistical obstacles to such a plan.  You'd need food, water, medicine.  You'd need engineers, doctors, nurses, endless oxygen, of which mars has none."  

    pge[6] = "So what is such a big deal here?" 


    for (i=0;i<=pge.length-1;i++) {
        var pgp = document.createElement("p");
        var txt = document.createTextNode(pge[i]);

        pgp.appendChild(txt);
        pgp.setAttribute("class","mine");

        pgp.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        pgp.setAttribute("style","color:#605;font-size:1.5em;");

        document.body.appendChild(pgp);
        txt = "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, check the value of `i`.  If it's 4 then it's the one you want to change.  So you can do something like this:

```
var len = pge.length;
for (var i=0; i< len;i++) { 
 if (i==4) { pgp.classList.add('redBG'); }
}
```

And have a CSS class:

```
.redBG {background-color:red; }
```

The best way to update the `class` is not using `setAttribute`.  Its by modifying the `classList` (for modern browsers).  In older broswers, you have to manually manipulate `className` as a string.

Also, you should ALWAYS `var` your variables.